# .net change tempFilesLocation for WCF client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

We are using WCF client in our project to communicate with an external SOAP web service. It looks like WCF needs to create some temp files to handle requests and because of our really restricted app container, we get a permission error message. To solve this problem, we should change the temp files location in the code (**not in the web.config** since we can not alter it)

Is there any way to change tempFilesLocation in **C# program**?

P.S: We are using Azure Functions App as our app container; So we cannot change web.config on the dynamic SKU.

Comment: That seems very much like an XY problem. Why would your WCF client create temp files? And even if... why would that not be allowed? It might be better to ask an open ended question on how to solve your actual problem.

Comment: @nvoigt WCF uses DataContractSerializer to create envelopes for SOAP request and that serializer needs to create temp files. Also Azure Functions App does not let you to have your own web.config or modify the existing one.

Comment: @nvoigt https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901(v=vs.110).aspx